# Google Cloud Vision Lower Case Upper Case

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

Sometimes the Google Cloud Vision API will return results with upper case labels and sometimes with lower case labels. For example, it may return "dress" or "Dress". Does anyone know if this signifies any difference?

Answer (score 0):

There could be some changes with the training data behind the API to use uppercase letters. Nevertheless, there should be no significant difference between the two for Label Detection.

I also tried [testing the API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart#make_a_request_to_the_cloud_vision_api_service), and the responses now consistently show in uppercase letters.